# Serve files from Firebase storage with Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Is it possible to setup a Firebase cloud function that serves a file from a Firebase cloud storage bucket to avoid using the long `firebasestorage.googleapis.com` link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. In that case you can even go without download URLs, since in Cloud Functions you'll have administrative access to all files in your Cloud Storage bucket anyway.